# dynamic DNS on Google Cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a bunch of servers that I want to start on Google Cloud.  I have one static IP that I have reserved, that's my "public" entry point to my system.

But I also need to be able to get to all my other servers directly.  I don't really care about what ephemeral IP is assigned to them, but it would be very convenient to be able to refer to them by name (rather than having to copy-and-paste the IP addresses from the console).

I see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34726498/how-to-update-google-cloud-dns-with-ephemeral-ip-for-an-instance), but I was hoping that there is a configuration option somewhere for this that does not involve scripting.

Answer (score 1):

The link what you have provided is a comprehensive answer. You can do it in several different ways (like using deployment manager or Cloud Functions), but at the end of the day it's still scripting.

However, if your issue is the changing IP's, you can reserve the IP's and reattach them if the instance gets recreated. ( You only need to pay for unattached reserved IP's.)

However it is questionable, why do you need direct access to all of your instances in a frequent basis other than their public/internal endpoints which could be a LoadBalancer.